PreSQL contains semicolons
I executed the following code and found the following issues：
select regexp_replace(e,';')  as d1

Presto SQL error, the main reason for the error is due to：
Presto treats semicolons as execution
How do I handle the above code

Works just fine for me, how exactly do you execute this SQL?
